# Injecting SMTPclient into a behavior, how to test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, architecture, dependency-injection

I'm setting up an application and I'm injecting a bunch of behaviors into a service using Unity. There is a constructor, something like:

```
public class WhateverService(IBehavior[] behaviors) : IService {}
```

All of this is set up like while setting up the container, something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IBehavior, LogBehavior>("LogBehavior");
container.RegisterType<IBehavior, SomeOtherBehavior>("SomeOtherBehavior");
container.RegisterType<IService, WhateverService>();
```

Injection is done in the WCF service project, obviously.

Now I want to add a MailNotificationBehavior. So there's a bunch of SMTP settings that need to save somewhere. Since this SMTP config is a deployment thing, I want to use deafault web.config SMTP settings configurations. 
The web.config is in the same project where the container configuration is being done, so the MailNotificationBehavior needs to be either injected with all of these settings, OR, just an instance of SmtpClient.

Something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IBehavior, MailNotificationBehavior>("MailNotificationBehavior", new new InjectionConstructor(new SmtpClient()));
```

Problem with this is - how will I be able to test this later on? 
Should I write an [interface ISmtpClient with an adapter for the actual SMTPClient](http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/07/20/unit-testing-with-email/), so I can fake it, or is this bad design to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you relying on injection in your automated tests? You could/should write a unit test which instantiates the service and setups the service with mock "behaviours".

Reasoning: Your unit test should isolate the lines you want to test. Using injection makes your unit test also about testing if the injection works and if the right behaviour is available in the context of your service. You don't want either if you write a test for the service.

About the design; altough design by interface is nice, it's overdesign if you never plan on switching concrete smtp libraries. Another thing that kinda smells is creating "Behaviour". Your service does something (has effect on it's surroundings etc), that's it's behaviour. The behaviour of your service is calling a method on the implementations of IBehaviour and thereby changing the application state.

What you actually want to do is use AOP to add logging / email behaviour to your application by implementing them as aspects.

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me elaborate a bit: the service is wrapped with logging/exceptionhandling/performance measurement/caching behaviors as you described, using AOP (I had a good mentor). However, the service itselft has a method - HandleMessage(). What I'm injecting here is Pre- and Post-handling behaviors. In some cases I want the service to e-mail as Post-Handling behavior, in some cases I don't. Therefore, I'm injecting it in the service, using the container. Now, if I want to test that behavior, I'll just instantiate the behavior, BUT providing an SMTPClient messes the test up.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to test if the service will execute the behaviour once under a certain preset messaging condition?

Since you designed by IBehaviour you don't want to know if the service sends an email or scratches a chiwawa's back. Thats why you abstracted with the IBehaviour interface. All you can really expect is the behaviour to be performed. So you could as well create a mock IBehaviour and set it up to behaviour once and inject that into the service in your test context.